# Escaping backslash in SQL Server GRANT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
GRANT SELECT ON tableName TO something\user_name
```

Unfortunately, when I execute this in SQL Server 2008 R2 I get an `Incorrect syntax near '\'.` error.

Is there a way to escape a backslash, or what should I do?

Comment: try `[something\user_name]`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
GRANT SELECT ON tableName TO [something\user_name]
```